# How can I get list of gradle plugins that a project will use

Tags: android, gradle, plugins

I would like to get the list of plugins in the Gradle's plugins block. "Project.plugins" will not achieve what I'm looking for.  By experimentation, I've discovered that "Project.plugins" is the set of plugins that have already been applied in the project.  What I want is the set of plugins declarative defined in the gradle.build script whether the plugin has yet to be applied or not. For example, I have a build.gradle script with a "plugins" block.  The first plugin I've added to block is "my.custom.plugin". When it gets applied, for diagnosis purposes it print the list of plugins in "Project.plugins". The printed list I get back contains the following plugins: HelpTasksPlugin, BuildInitPlugin and WrapperPlugin.  Here's what the build.gradle script looks like:

```
 plugins{
     id("my.custom.plugin")
     id("com.android.application")
 }
```

I was hoping that the plugin "com.android.application" would have been in that list. Since it wasn't, that's why I say that "Project.plugins" is the list of applied plugins.  "My.custom.plugin" was also not in that list and I guessing that's because the plugin is in the process of being applied, but not yet completed being applied.

What I was hoping to do in "my.custom.plugin" was to see that if the project contains the "com.android.application" plugin, I would do some special processing like configuring android's AppExtension.  So my question is: is there a way for me to get the id's of all the plugins in the "plugins" block, whether the plugin has yet to be applied or not?  So why not apply the "com.android.application" plugin before applying "my.custom.plugin"?  Well the short of that is that I've also discovered that applying "com.android.application" without any "android" AppExtension in the build.gradle fails because it wants to know compileSdkVersion, but it won't know that until "my.custom.plugin is applied which defines that value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you actually want to do in your plugin is to create a `beforeEvaluate { }` hook, which will execute after plugins have been applied, but before Gradle resolves all references to things, giving you a chance to change any settings or setup before tasks execute.

```java
class MyCustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.beforeEvaluate {
            if (project.getPluginManager().hasPlugin("com.android.application")) {
                throw new GradleException("com.android.application already applied");
            } else {
                // Do your plugin setup here
                project.getPluginManager().apply("com.android.application");    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately it doesn't quite do what I need it to do.  What happens is that the com.android.application plugin gets applied before my.custom.plugin.  But I need my.custom.plugin to be apply before com.android.application because it sets up the android AppExtension. If I didn't have that order dependency, what you're saying is correct that all the plugins would have been applied, and therefore com.android.application would be in the lists of plugins. I think I'm going to need to change the way I approach this problem.

Comment: If you need to control the application of `com.android.application`, then your plugin needs to be responsible for applying it. Include that plugins JAR in your plugin's dependencies, then you apply it when your are ready.

Comment: I updated the answer with manual application. I believe you can still apply plugins in `beforeEvaluate { }`, but I have not verified this. Simply doing this check in the main `apply()` of your plugin would not be enough, because you need to do the check after all user plugins have been applied.

Comment: Yeah, that's the approach I'm taking, but I've run into another new challenge.  It's a little difficult to create a new android AppExtension or LibraryExtension.  The constructor for those classes require a number of internal dsl classes to initialize them.  I've got a number of ideas on how to try to get around that issue but I'm still trying to see if I can accomplish that.  I accept your revised answer as the correct answer to my posted question.  My new issue is outside of the scope the posted question.  I really appreciate your assistance. Good job!

Comment: For the benefit of others reading this post, what I'm trying to accomplish is to simplify the build.gradle scripts. Almost everything in the "android" block for my projects are pretty well boilerplate.   By applying my custom plugin, I'm hoping to simply the build script to be a set of plugins and a set of dependencies and eliminate the need to add an android block to the build.gradle.kts script all together. It's a neat idea but might not be possible to achieve that due to various sundry reasons. I was hoping to eliminate the need for a cut and paste of a boilerplate into a project.

Comment: Hearing more details, I don’t think a plugin is the thing you actually need. I think what you need are precompiled build scripts: https://antimonit.github.io/2020/12/06/to-buildsrc-and-back.html

Comment: I believe the correct name for these is “convention plugins”. Gradle lets you define a normal Gradle file, and it compiles them into plugins that you just apply as a normal plugin. There should be a way to publish these to a Maven repo and share them.

Comment: I think you're right.  I looked at the documentation and it looks like it is doing exactly what I need it to do.  There's something known as "includeBuild" which I'm just beginning to explore.  That might be the way around publishing and sharing.  What I've read is that included builds are equivalent to buildSrc.

Comment: Just for closure, I got this working.  You don't need to solve this problem using precompiled scripts.  It can be done solely with a custom external plugin.  Precompiled scripts, for simplicity's sake, allows one to effective convert DSL code into a plugin.  It generates a class that extends Plugin<Project> with contains the "apply" function.  There's a convention on what the Id of a precompiled plugin script is.  But it turns out to be just a plugin (internally contained in buildSrc). For my situation, an external plugin  is more manageable.